# What is the etiquette for re-proposing one of your own questions to be closed?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I asked a [duplicate question here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48608/), and it is so undeniably a duplicate that it received the [same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48608/) [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23793/)! Even if I disagree that it is an answer at all, the fact remains that the question was a duplicate. Early in the question's life, its duplicate status was pointed out and I cast my own close vote. But today I noticed it is devoid of votes, and pwa, the votes to close have expired!

Let's shoot the long story before it actually gets long: I can't cast another vote, so I cannot reopen it for closing review. Should I have flagged this for moderator attention? Or should I just sit tight knowing that the community disagreed with closing it? What is the general protocol for this situation in general?

I searched and found mostly posts about when you should close your own questions. I never quite found anything on the subject of what should be done when your attempt to close your question failed and you still believe it should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a duplicate, go ahead an flag it for moderator review. They can decide whether it is duplicate worthy. If they don't believe it is duplicate worthy, then leave it (maybe accept my answer :P )

If it was for another reason, you would probably want to sit tight an accept that we didn't close it.

Comment: Accepting this, covers more ground in general. Also, I refuse to accept your answer on the discussed question because I think it's a complete non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the answers have upvotes, you can bypass the closing process altogether and just delete it yourself.  (Not the case here, but good to keep in mind generally.)

Otherwise, all you can really do is flag it for a mod and ask for a close/delete/merge.

Comment: -1. Deleting duplicate questions is bad [link pending]

Comment: Note I wasn't the one who downvoted (I did at first and then undid it)

Comment: @Earlz: That link is going to point to advice for 10k users on deleting closed questions; *those* deletions are harmful because the questions may have good answers and/or a different wording that aids in searching. If the question is *so obviously* a duplicate that the *original author* realizes it *and* the question has no upvoted answers, then the question doesn't need to be left lying around.  You're referring to a different aspect of the site.

Comment: Is it that an answer cannot have any upvotes, or that the total score for all answers cannot exceed 1? Field testing shows the former but the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222) states the latter.